# Ending Game When Turtle Reaches Edge of Grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have to write a program that implements the use of Turtle Graphics. I have already wrote majority of the program which includes the grid and creation of multiple turtles, but I am having a hard time ending the game once a turtle reaches the edge of the grid I created. Here is what I have so far:

```
import turtle
import random

# Setting up Turtle Graphics Window
turtle.setup(800,600)
window = turtle.Screen()
window.title("Turtles Walking through Grid")
window.bgcolor("black")


# Making the turtle
grid = turtle.getturtle()
grid.shape("classic")
grid.color("white")
grid.speed(10)

# Creating the Grid (Relative Positioning)
grid.penup()
grid.setposition(-300,200)
grid.pendown()
grid.forward(600)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(600)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(400)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(600)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(600)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(600)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(600)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(600)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(600)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(600)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(600)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.right(90)
grid.forward(600)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(40)
grid.left(90)
grid.forward(600)

# User Input for Speed 
speed = int(input("Enter the speed of the turtles (1-10): "))

# Variable for choosing colors
all_colors =      ["red","white","blue","hotpink","purple","lightgreen","yellow"]

# Creating the turtles
def createTurtles(turtle_count):
    count = []
    for k in range(0, turtle_count):
        lil_guys = turtle.Turtle()
        lil_guys.shape("turtle")
        colors = random.choice(all_colors)
        lil_guys.color(colors)
        lil_guys.speed(speed)
        lil_guys.pendown()
        count.append(lil_guys)
    return count

# Determine where the Turtle should stop
def off_board(self):
    x = self.turtle.xcor()
    y = self.turtle.ycor()
    return x < -160 or 160 < x or y < -160 or 160 < y

# Set Turtle Amount to 5
count = createTurtles(5)
fun = True

while fun:
    for k in range(5):
        coin = random.randrange(0, 2)
        if coin == 0:
            count[k].left(90)
        else:
            count[k].right(90)

        count[k].forward(40)

# Exit on close window
turtle.exitonclick()
```

The program is supposed to end once one of the five turtle have reached the edge of the grid I created.

Answer (score 1):

#### Exiting at the edge of the grid

You can exit when a turtle reaches the edge of the grid as follows:

```
while fun:
    for k in range(5):
        coin = random.randrange(0, 2)
        if coin == 0:
            count[k].left(90)
        else:
            count[k].right(90)

        count[k].forward(40)

        x = count[k].xcor()          # new lines
        y = count[k].ycor()          # |
                                     # |
        if x < -300 or 300 < x or \  # |
           y < -200 or 200 < y:      # |
            fun = False              # |
            break                    # |
```

You're on the right track by putting this logic into an `off_grid` function, but this function should not take `self` as an argument (it's not an instance of a class).

---

#### Design suggestions

I have some general design suggestions to offer (pardon the imprompteau code review):

- Avoid global variables; use parameters to pass information into functions. This keeps the functions [re-usable](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-python/9781491919521/ch04.html) and safe. Think of each function as a black box with adjustable knobs (the parameters); this black box should work independently and not break or work differently if exterior state changes unpredictably. This reduces bugs and makes your program easier to reason about.
- Use accurate variable names. `count` is not really a `count` of anything, but rather a list of `turtle`s. Meaningful names make it easier to follow your logic and avoid bugs and misunderstandings. The variable `fun` could be clearer as `running`. The variable `k` in `for k in range(0, turtle_count):` is unused and is typically written as `_` in Python.
- Prefer `snake_case` for [function names in Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (`CamelCase` is used for classes).
- Instead of many lines of commands in sequence, use a loop to draw the grid and keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (don't repeat yourself). For example:

  ```
  for _ in range(0, height + 1, grid_size):
      turtle.pendown()
      turtle.forward(width)
      turtle.penup()
      turtle.right(90)
      turtle.forward(grid_size)
      turtle.right(90)
      turtle.forward(width)
      turtle.right(180)
  ```
- Avoid [hardcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) numbers and strings; place all of these variables at the top of your `main` program and use them throughout. Specifically, in this program, you're in need of `height`, `width` and `grid_size` parameters that will be defined in one location and govern the operation of the entire program (including determining when a turtle has left the grid). Now, if I decide I want a grid size of 30, a height of 200 and a width of 400, for example, I can change those numbers in one place and everything just works.
- Use Python's default parameters or dictionaries to reduce the burden of excessive parameters to functions. Place functions at the top of your script and separate them from `main`.
- Comments are good, but comments when the code is already obvious often add noise:

  ```
  # Exit on close window
  turtle.exitonclick()
  ```
- Keep the user in mind: I wasn't aware I had to go back to the terminal to input the turtle speed after the grid was drawn. I'd prefer to prompt the user for turtle speed, then run the visual portion of the program.

---

#### A possible refactor

Putting it all together, here's a suggested first refactor (there is still much room for design improvement, but this should provide some food for thought):

```
import turtle
import random

def create_turtles(
    turtle, turtle_count, colors, speed=10, shape="turtle"
):
    turtles = []

    for _ in range(turtle_count):
        tur = turtle.Turtle()
        tur.shape(shape)
        tur.color(random.choice(colors))
        tur.speed(speed)
        tur.pendown()
        turtles.append(tur)

    return turtles

def draw_lines(turtle, turn, length_a, length_b, grid_size):
    for _ in range(0, length_a + 1, grid_size):
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(length_b)
        turtle.penup()
        turn(90)
        turtle.forward(grid_size)
        turn(90)
        turtle.forward(length_b)
        turn(180)

def draw_grid(
    turtle, width=600, height=400, grid_size=40, 
    speed=100, shape="classic", color="white"
):
    tur = turtle.getturtle()
    tur.shape(shape)
    tur.color(color)
    tur.speed(speed)
    tur.penup()

    tur.setposition(-width // 2, height // 2)
    draw_lines(tur, tur.right, height, width, grid_size)

    tur.setposition(-width // 2, height // 2)
    tur.right(90)
    draw_lines(tur, tur.left, width, height, grid_size)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.ht()

def off_grid(turtle, width, height):
    x = turtle.xcor()
    y = turtle.ycor()

    return x < -width // 2 or x > width // 2 or \
           y < -height // 2or y > height // 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    grid_size = 40
    height = 400
    width = 600
    all_colors = [
        "red", "white", "blue", "hotpink", 
        "purple", "lightgreen", "yellow"
    ]

    speed = int(input("Enter the speed of the turtles (1-10): "))

    turtle.setup(800, 600)
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.title("Turtles Walking through Grid")
    window.bgcolor("black")

    draw_grid(turtle, width, height, grid_size)
    turtles = create_turtles(turtle, 5, all_colors, speed)
    running = True

    while running:
        for tur in turtles:
            random.choice([tur.left, tur.right])(90)
            tur.forward(grid_size)

            if off_grid(tur, width, height):
                running = False
                break

    turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: As I noted in my answer, I appreciate the advice you gave the OP (+1).  One glitch you inherit from the OP's code is a parity problem.  I.e. the turtles walk on lines in one dimension, between them in another.  If you change your grid width to 400, then they walk completely on the lines.  This really should be independent of grid size and I've tried to address it in my example code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to duplicate all of @ggorlen's excellent advice (+1), but rather point out some other issues:

- Your turtles walk *on* the grid lines in one dimension and walk *between* the grid lines in another.  In my rework below, they walk *on* the grid lines.  This requires a calculation based on the (parity of the) sizes you choose for your grid.
- In my rework, movement stops when a turtle reaches the *edge* of the grid which is clearer since they are walking *on* the grid lines.
- Avoid using "white" as a turtle color if you're going to have the pen down and white grid lines!  Ditto for "black" as a turtle color.
- If/when you can, avoid making the user go outside the program to input parameters.  As @ggorlen notes, doing the `input()` before invoking turtle helps.  But in my rework, I've used `numinput()`, new in Python 3, to keep it all in the GUI.
- There are lots of algorithms for drawing a grid in turtle, pick one and use it!

The reworked code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

TURTLE_COUNT = 5

# Variable for choosing colors
ALL_COLORS = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'purple']

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800, 600
GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT = 600, 400
CELL_SIZE = 40  # should be a divisor of GRID_WIDTH and GRID_HEIGHT, and probably no smaller than CURSOR_SIZE

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

# Creating the turtles
def create_turtles(turtle_count, speed):
    turtles = []

    for index in range(turtle_count):
        lil_guy = Turtle('turtle')
        lil_guy.color(ALL_COLORS[index % TURTLE_COUNT])
        lil_guy.speed(speed)
        lil_guy.penup()
        # to place a turtle cleanly on the grid lines, we have to consider the parity of the grid size
        lil_guy.goto((GRID_WIDTH / CELL_SIZE % 2) * CELL_SIZE/2, (GRID_HEIGHT / CELL_SIZE % 2) * CELL_SIZE/2)
        lil_guy.pendown()

        turtles.append(lil_guy)

    return turtles

# Determine where the Turtle should stop
def on_edge(turtle):
    x, y = turtle.position()
    return abs(x) >= (GRID_WIDTH/2 - CELL_SIZE/2) or abs(y) >= (GRID_HEIGHT/2 - CELL_SIZE/2)

# Setting up Turtle Graphics Window
window = Screen()
window.setup(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
window.title("Turtles Walking through Grid")
window.bgcolor('black')

# Create the grid via stamping
grid = Turtle(visible=False)
grid.speed('fastest')
grid.color('white')
grid.penup()

grid.setx(-GRID_WIDTH/2)
grid.shapesize(GRID_HEIGHT*2 / CURSOR_SIZE, 1/CURSOR_SIZE)

for _ in range(GRID_WIDTH // CELL_SIZE + 1):
    grid.stamp()
    grid.forward(CELL_SIZE)

grid.setheading(90)

grid.setposition(0, -GRID_HEIGHT/2)
grid.shapesize(GRID_WIDTH*2 / CURSOR_SIZE, 1/CURSOR_SIZE)

for _ in range(GRID_HEIGHT // CELL_SIZE + 1):
    grid.stamp()
    grid.forward(CELL_SIZE)

# User Input for Speed
user_speed = window.numinput("Turtle Speed", "Enter a value (1-10)", default=5, minval=1, maxval=10)

# Set Turtle Amount
turtles = create_turtles(TURTLE_COUNT, user_speed)

finished = False

while not finished:
    for k in range(5):
        angle = choice([90, -90])

        turtles[k].left(angle)
        turtles[k].forward(CELL_SIZE)

        finished = on_edge(turtles[k])
        if finished:
            break

# Exit on close window
window.exitonclick()
```